# Issue with PrestoDB & MongoDB

Tags: presto

I having some strange issues querying mongodb from presto CLI. I have my mongodb.properties set and connecting to 3 different databases as shown below.

`connector.name=mongodb
    mongodb.seeds=172.23.0.7:27017
    mongodb.schema-collection=stage,configuration,hub
    mongodb.credentials=<username>:<password>@stage,<username>:<password>@hub,<username>:<password>@configuration`

None of the queries including `show columns from <collection>` or `select count(*) from <collection>` is not working on stage or hub and for collections in configuration too.

Question is, does Presto support these kind of queries on MongoDB. If yes, what could be the problem with my configuration or queries. Our intention is to compare data from Oracle to MongoDB.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: "not working" is not very helpful. Do you get an error, and if so, what does it say? Do you get no results? What?

Comment: I apologize. When I say "not working", it's not showing the total number of documents in some collections. I have about 113 collections and the only 15 collections are showing up with results and column names. For the rest shows zero documents and columns.

Comment: We figured out what the problem was. Our databases and collections had names in title case. Queries were executing fine only for lowercase collections. It could be an issue as we are using Linux and they seem to be case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I hope this is still useful for future users. You shouldn't be setting the `mongodb.schema-collection` as such. This property is meant to point to the mongo collection which describes the schema of other collections, typically defaulting to `_schema` when it exists. This is covered in the docs of most presto distributions, including [prestodb](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/mongodb.html).

This does not allow you to control which collections Presto will have access to, this must be done elsewhere (e.g. when setting up presto's user in the MongoDB cluster). Once correctly set up, Presto will be able to perform queries such as the ones in your example in all the collections it has access to.